# No text in spinner when setting its background image

Tags: java, android, spinner

My spinner dislpays no text. It has background like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/spin_bg" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/spin_bg" />
```

And my spin_bg.9.png looks like this:

[image]

What i get is this (no text):

[image]

Comment: Maybe your font color is black as well?

Comment: You are right. Please make it an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really glad i could help you

Answer as per OP's request:
Your font color is black.